# Kivy: How do I add a context menu to button

Tags: python, user-interface, button, kivy, contextmenu

I have created a custom `Button` class in Kivy with some callback methods, when I right click on the button I want to be able to choose from a couple of different actions:

```
from kivy.config import Congfig
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix import Button


class CustomButton(Button):
   """This is just for demonstration"""

   def __init__(self, name='', **kwargs):
       super(Service, self).__init__(**kwargs)
       self.name = name
       self.on_touch_down = self.mouse_click

   def mouse_click(self, touch):
       if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
           if touch.button == 'right':
               # Open context menu
               pass

   def callback_1(self):
       # This will be called from one of the context options
       pass

   def callback_2(self):
       # Or this will be called from a different option
       pass
```

The code is just for demonstration purposes to express what I'm trying to achieve. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your `mouse_click()` method (where you have `# Open context menu`) you can call a custom popup menu like:

```
self.popup = PopMenu(touch)
self.popup.open()
```

With a PopMenu class that creates a `ModalView`, something like:

```
class PopMenu(object):

    def __init__(self, touch):
        myContent = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        button = Button(text='button1')
        myContent.add_widget(button)
        button = Button(text='button2')
        myContent.add_widget(button)
        button = Button(text='button3')
        myContent.add_widget(button)
        self.popup = ModalView(size_hint=(None, None), height=myContent.height, pos_hint={'x' : touch.spos[0], 'top' : touch.spos[1]})
        self.popup.add_widget(myContent)

    def open(self, *args):
        self.popup.open()
```

And you can add your callbacks to the buttons in the PopMenu.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks for your contribution :)